# Ruby group by range, array of numbers?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to create a histogram from an array of numbers in the range `[0,1]`.

Is there a way to use `group_by` to separate the array into N groups/bins by numeric interval (or some other fun Ruby one-liner)?

This is my current, boring, solution:

```
# values == array containing floating point numbers in the range [0,1]

n = 10

# EDITED from Array.new(n, 0) to Array.new(n, []), thanks emaillenin!
histogram = Array.new(n, [])
values.each do |val|
  histogram[(val * n).ceil - 1].push(val)
end
```

Comment: this code wouldn't work. histogram[anything] is a Fixnum and you cannot call push on it

Comment: @emaillenin oops you're correct!  I meant that to be an array of arrays, my bad!

Comment: Should be `Array.new(n) { [ ] }` to avoid all slots referencing the same array.

Comment: Why does it have to be a one-liner? That constraint often results in code that is hard to read or understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do but maybe this helps?

```
values = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
values.group_by { |v| (v * 10).ceil - 1 }
```

That returns a hash:

```
{-1=>[0.0], 0=>[0.1], 1=>[0.2], 2=>[0.3]}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this can yield up to 11 buckets when both `0.0` and `1.0` are present in addition to the other values (`0.x`).

Comment: `group_by` does this very cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it.

**Code**

```
def freq_by_bin(nbr_bins, *values)
  nbr_bins.times.to_a.product([0]).to_h.tap { |h|
    values.each { |v| h.update({ (v*nbr_bins).to_i=>1 }) { |_,o,_| o+1 } } }
end
```

**Example**

```
values =  [0.30, 0.25, 0.63, 0.94, 0.08, 0.94, 0.01,
           0.41, 0.28, 0.69, 0.61, 0.12, 0.66]
freq_by_bin(10, *values)
  #=> {0=>2, 1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>1, 4=>1,
  #    5=>0, 6=>4, 7=>0, 8=>0, 9=>2}

def histogram(nbr_bins, *values)
  h = freq_by_bin(nbr_bins, *values)
  puts "\nfreq"
  h.values.max.downto(0) do |n|
    print "%2d|" % n
    puts nbr_bins.times.with_object('   ') { |i,row|
           row << ((h[i]==n) ? ' X ' : '   ') }
  end
  puts "   __"+"___"*nbr_bins
  puts nbr_bins.times.each_with_object('      ') { |i,row| row << "%2d " % i }
end

histogram(10, *values)

freq
 4|                      X          
 3|                                 
 2|    X     X                    X 
 1|       X     X  X                
 0|                   X     X  X    
   ________________________________
       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

**Notes**

- There are several ways to construct the hash whose elements are `bin=>freq`.  Using [Enumerable#group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), which you mentioned and @diego used is one.  I've used the form of [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `Hash#merge!`) that takes a block.
- I used [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-tap) merely to avoid the need to create a temporary (non-block) variable for the initialized hash.